# concat 2 column values on JOIN sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

```
Table One


ID  Code    Amount
1   2       100
2   2       200


Table Two

ID  Key     Description
1   12      Bag
2   22      Cap
```

I want to join select two tables on joining 2 columns for one table. Say in table table I want to join them when t1.id + t1. code = t2.key. In graphical I want to get `22 = 22` or `12 = 12` where in `22 or 21` in first side is `t1.id+t1.code`

**Query:**

```
Select * 
from table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON (t1.id +""+ t1.code)= t2.key
```

**Error:**

> Msg 1038, Level 15, State 4, Line 1
>   An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `''` for empty string:

```
Select * 
from table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON (t1.id +''+ t1.code)= t2.[key]
-- key is reserved keyword so you need to quote it
```

Or `CONCAT`:

```
Select * 
from table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON CONCAT(t1.id, t1.code)= t2.[key];
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/LTJ40577)**

If columns are `INT` you also need to cast them like: `CAST(t1.id AS VARCHAR(10))`.

Be aware that your join will perform poorly.